# prove that the probability of not occurring B given that A-B has occurred is equal to 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I found this statement given as true in a a,b,c,d kind of question on a solved exam on probability but no explanation. I think it is pretty intuitive, but how can I properly prove it given I have studied the basics about set and probability theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(B^c|A\setminus B)=P(B^c|A\cap B^c)=\frac{P(B^c\cap A\cap B^c)}{P(A\cap B^c)}=1$$ Assuming $P(A\cap B^c)\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you.I didn’t remember the fact that A-B is equal to A∩B^c

Answer (score 0):

For $2$ events, $A$ and $B$ ...
$A$ can occur
$B$ can occur
$A \cap B$ can occur
$A - B$ can occur
$B - A$ can occur

IF $A - B$ occurs, $A \cap B$ did not occur. We already know $B - A$ did not occur. That means all possibilities in which $B$ can occur have been eliminated. Ergo $B$ did not occur i.e $P(B \space not \space occurring) = 1$